# How to build and Use a Basic/Simple Meteor package that uses react-meteor

Tags: meteor, package, meteor-react

I am new to Meteor and learning Meteorjs with Reactjs. I want to know how one can build a simple (eg. Todo App's package) meteor package that uses react-meteor, and how can I use it in our project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Meteor - React tutorial for beginners in the official Meteor page [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app). You should also read the [official Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html) for more information about React in Meteor after completing the tutorial.